# Cannot Bind Macro To Keyboard Shortcut In Word 2016

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm helping to automate some work we're doing at my office. Our users love having quick keyboard shortcuts to invoke macros.  Today I ran across a rather odd situation.  I tried to bind a macro to Shift+Ctrl+I.  When I press that keystroke combination, nothing happens.  And when I say "nothing", I mean nothing. A breakpoint set in the sub doesn't even get hit so it seems as if the macro isn't getting invoked at all.

The same macro runs just fine when I invoke it from the Developer/Macro menu.  It also works if I bind it to Alt+Shift+I.  No change to the code whatever. So it doesn't seem to be a coding issue at all. Plus other existing macros work via keystroke shortcuts so that doesn't seem to be a problem either.

Searching for known issues about binding Ctrl+Shift+I didn't turn up anything.  I remove the key binding and it italicizes the text just like it should so there doesn't seem to be any issue with my keyboard (and another user sees the same problem so it doesn't seem likely to be hardware either).

Is this a known issue and I just didn't find it by Googling?  I mean I can, of course bind to Alt+Shift+I so I have a simple work around but I just want to know if there's something else I'm not seeing.

MS Word MSO 2016(16.0.4738.1000) 64-Bit on Windows 10.

Comment: FWIW assigning a macro to Ctrl+Shift+I works for me, but I have Office 365, which is updated automatically. If there was once a problem (I've never heard of one) it's been corrected. Have you tried binding to any other macros? It's also possible that something in Windows or some other program is interfering (even though the built-in shortcut is working). You might also try renaming Normal.dotm so that Word generates a new copy and test that, just for the sake of thoroughness.

Comment: It must be something about that one document.  I just tried a different macro (but in a different doc) and I was able to assign it to Ctrl+Shift+I so it's nothing inherent in Word.

Comment: In that case, this one document may be damaged. You can try saving as *.doc, open, then save again as docm (or dot / dotm if this is a template), see if that cleans it up...